# Create View creating problems

Tags: sql, view, where-clause

```
CREATE VIEW UrgentQuantity AS 
select sum(L_QUANTITY) 
FROM LINEITEM
INNER JOIN ORDERS
ON O_ORDERKEY = L_ORDERKEY 
WHERE O_ORDERPRIORITY = '1-URGENT'
```

The above code completely functions without the line:

```
CREATE VIEW UrgentQuantity AS
```

What I am confounded with currently is however that the error message says:

> [15:23:55] Error while executing SQL query on database 'tpch': near " WHERE": syntax error

Implying that the issue lies with the 'where' statement, even though that was functioning earlier.

Comment: for the goodness sake, what is your database? you managed to mention not a single one

Comment: At the very least, you need to give `sum(L_QUANTITY)` a name. `sum(L_QUANTITY) as <something>`.  Not sure what the value of a 1 column, 1 row view is though...

Comment: @Andrew can  you explain why?